# Editing the variables of a running java program

Tags: java, parsing

say i have a java program with a string in it. I have this program running.

Now i want to make another java program which can change the value of this string. is this possible?

Comment: You can run the first program under a debugger (the second program). The first program can also provide a service to other programs, which allows client to tweak the server's settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java strings are immutable.  Technically you can't "change the value."  There are multiple options on what you can do, depending on what you're aiming to do.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: java program A lets you write text and change the text colour, I want java program B to change the colour without having to edit the code of program A. Im guessing from what ive read the easiest thing to do would be to edit the memory addresses?

Answer (score 1):

No and yes.

No, because you cannot access variables in a running process directly. However, you can make your program listen on a port or use another way of interprocess communication, wait for connections from other processes, and change the variable in accordance to the message it receives.